# Why do the occasional ajax requests return an error response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This bug is really frustrating me and I am hoping the fine folks here at SO can help at least give me some clues as to what to look for.  I have set up an order tracking system using ajax and it works with like 95% of the requests.  However some are running the function that is in the error response.. for example :

```
function trackIt(){
    $j("#result").html(" ");
    $j("resultTwo").html(" ");
    var ordervalue = $j('#order').val();
    if ((ordervalue.length == 9) || (ordervalue.length == 5)) {
        $j.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('web') ?>/index/trackOrder',
            data: 'increment_id='+ ordervalue,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $j('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif" alt="" />');
            },
            success: tracker,
            error : function (xhr, status, error) {
                wtf();
            }
        });
    } else { return false; };
};
```

I can see in firebug that the json data is returning as it should but for a couple of tracking numbers it is running the wtf function?!  WTF?  What else can I look for?  Why is it considering some requests an error?  What can I look for?  Is there something wrong with how I am making these requests?  Let me know if you need more information or anything to help you help me.

Thanks in advance for any help.. all I want for Christmas is for this damn thing to work!

Edit :

Here is an example of the JSON response that is not being returned.

```
{"Debug":"3","Status":"Closed","Date":"2011-12-15T22:53:09","Description": "<div class=\"orderProduct\">Sector 9 J-Bay Bamboo Longboard  - Color: ASSORTED, Size: 10</div><div class=\"orderProduct\">Kahuna Haka Cruiser Skateboard  - Color: ASSORTED, Size: ONE SIZE</div><div class=\"orderProduct\">Santa Cruz Primo Pintail 9.9" Longboard Cruiser  - Color: ASSORTED, Size: ONE SIZE","ProcessorId":"0","Sku": "16389400070018<br>17748800070018<br>18777606960012","Method":"Free Shipping","ShippingCo":"UPS Ground","Track":""}
```

Here is an example of one that is being returned.

```
{"Debug":"1","Status":"Closed","Date":"2011-12-15T22:33:32","Description": "<div class=\"orderProduct\">Supra Dixon Black Canvas Shoe  - Color: BLACK, Size: 12","ProcessorId":"0","Sku": "16086200010046","Method":"Ship To Store - In Store Pickup","ShippingCo":"Ship To Store - In Store Pickup","Track":"1Z68W0376038395"}
```

One obvious difference is that debug value which unfortunately I have no idea what that means.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, perhaps some numbers you are passing aren't valid and thus return an error.  You should look at the actual network traffic and see what is really being returned.  You can do that in the network tab in the Chrome inspector or also in Firebug (in Firefox).

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could record, and post here, a couple of 'status' and 'error' values in error function rather than just calling wtf(). Those arguments are there to tell you what went wrong :)

Comment: Perhaps you could post the JSON response so people can help verify that it's as correct as you think it is.

Comment: @jfriend the number is valid and I see in the inspector that all of the json data i need is being passed correctly

Comment: @d-live and pointy. sorry i am just frustrated thats why my stupid joke of a function.  I did have this `console.log("status" + xhr.status);` and `console.log("error" + thrownError);` but all I get is a 200 status and no error message.  It is a puzzler.

Comment: I added an example of the json response I am seeing that is causing the error and I am adding another one that doesnt cause an error.

Comment: I think it's hilarious that the parser *for StackOverflow* noticed the problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example of JSON that causes the error is invalid JSON.  Right around here:

```
>Santa Cruz Primo Pintail 9.9" Longboard Cruiser  - Color:
```

it goes wrong.

I'm not sure exactly what it's supposed to be, but I would presume the JSON parser is throwing an error because of the bad JSON.

Comment: Ahhh yes! It must be that extra quote in there.  Any ideas on how I could escape that?  At least I have something to go on now.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You put a backslash in front of that quote like all the other embedded quotes.

Comment: Yea but I cant control the data at that level.  I am just pulling the json... this may require a new question :/  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you're going to try to "fix" the JSON yourself on the client-side, good luck.  I have no idea how you could know the difference between an intended quote and a quote missing an escape.  You'd also have to set dataType to something other than JSON so you could examine the text yourself, fix it, then parse it yourself.  What a mess.  The data should be fixed at the source.

Comment: If you can identify some common pattern to the goof, then you could make some sort of .replace() operation using a regex to find the pattern and a replacement string to fix it.  But, this could only work if you can find a way to analyze and find the goofs in the JSON.

Comment: You could also hack away on a JSON parser to not just give up when it gets an error, but to skip forward to the next valid data it can find and understand and keep going.  This is dangerous because you never really know what you'll get or how good you'll be at this.  You may end with partial data or wrong data if you guess wrong.

Comment: ahhh good times.  Well I will see what I can figure out.  Thanks a lot for you help I really appreciate it.  Cheers.

Comment: Here's a giant hack that fixes that one example.  Basically it looks for double quotes that aren't escapes and don't appear to match the end of a JSON string: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/r7UyT/.  When it's done, it passes `JSON.parse()` and gives the desired answer.  This is a testbed with lots of intermediary values and intermediary replaces just to help with the problem solving.  It could be shortened.  This also assumes that all JSON errors that need fixing look like your one example.

Comment: @Zac -- seriously, that way lies madness. The source you are using is simply not creating JSON and there's no way to pretend it is with the tools at your disposal.  Contact the person who runs the website and have him fix it.